# Selecting parts of an element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="foo">
    <span>
        <a href="#" class="no-want">X</a>
        &nbsp;
        1
    </span>
    <span>
        <a href="#" class="no-want">X</a>
        &nbsp;
        2
    </span>
    <span>
        <a href="#" class="no-want">X</a>
        &nbsp;
        Hello
    </span>
</div>
```

I want to use jQuery to get only the following `1`, `2` and `hello` in JS (that means no `<a>` tags or `&nbsp;`). Please note that *I do not want to affect the DOM itself*.  I just want to retrieve the text in an object such as an array.

This is what I have so far:

```
$('#foo span');
```

However I can't seem to remove the "a" tag.

The following does not seem to work either:

```
$('#foo span').remove('a');
```

I'm also aware that `.remove()` affects the DOM it self, and does not just retrieve the text.

Comment: Try: `$('#foo span a').remove();`

Comment: What do you mean by "get"? Do you want the number in a variable? You can not get a reference to the node of the number, because the number is not a full node.

Comment: Remove is simple...`get` and `display` however are not the same things. What is actual objective?

Comment: Clarifying question now

Comment: If you're trying to select *part* of a text node using just css selectors, then no - that's not possible.  If you're trying to select just the text nodes while ignoring adjacent elements, then you want `.contents()`, but it will give you the whole text in that node so you'll have to manipulate it after.

Comment: I guess he is trying to parse the number inside the `span` tag. This can't be done with pure CSS, you need JS and a pattern so it can be parsed.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be a number. (see updated question)

Comment: The idea is the same, you want to parse the value after `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution creates array by looping over each child and cloning it to do manipulation so dom stays intact

```
var values = $('#foo').children().map(function () {
    var $clone = $(this).clone();
    $clone.children().remove();
    return $.trim($clone.text());    
}).get();

console.log(values) /// ["1","2","Hello"]
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/adp9t1fv/1)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code will get that value for you:

```
$('#foo span').each(function(){
    console.log($.trim($(this).html().substring($(this).html().lastIndexOf("&nbsp;") + 6)));
});
```

Working jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mrwqs2nb/1/

Open the console, you will see:

```
1
2
Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using RegEx to match what you want

```
$('#foo span').each(function () {
  alert($(this).html().match(/[0-9]/));
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/x9c0qa52/)

Comment: Not necessarily a number.

Answer (score 0):

Since your problem is not detailed , on the basis of your requirements , this can be done as below

```
   var res=[];
    $('#foo span').map(function(i){
    var htm=$(this).text();
    var htm_d=$(this).find('a').html();
    htm=$.trim(htm.split("").reverse().join(""));
    htm_d=$.trim(htm_d.split("").reverse().join(""));
    res[i] = htm.substring(0,htm_d.length); 
    } );
    alert(res);
```

LIVE http://jsfiddle.net/mailmerohit5/5bvavx0p/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the rules of this game are, but if it can be asumed that what you want is on the right of the `&nbsp;` then this should do it:

```
$('#foo span').map(function() {
    //Split at the space.
    var parts = $(this).html().split('&nbsp;');
    //Remove the first element from the list.
    parts.shift();
    //Join and return.
    return parts.join('');
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using selector `$("foo span")` , `$.map()` , `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `[0-9]+|[a-z]+[^\s+|\n+|" + el.querySelector(".no-want").textContent + "]", "ig"` to match digit or characters `a-z` case insensitive , negating space character , or newline character , or `".no-want"` element `.textContent` at `index` of parent `span` element

```js
var res = $.map($("#foo span"), function(el, index) {
            return el.textContent.match(new RegExp("[0-9]+|[a-z]+[^\s+|\n+|" 
                   + el.querySelector(".no-want").textContent.trim() + "]", "ig"))
          });
console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
  <span>
        <a href="#" class="no-want">X</a>
        &nbsp;
        1
    </span>
  <span>
        <a href="#" class="no-want">X</a>
        &nbsp;
        2
    </span>
  <span>
        <a href="#" class="no-want">X</a>
        &nbsp;
        Hello
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery's [contents](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) - the api page has an example on how to extra text nodes while ignoring other elements.

```
var result = $("#foo span")
             .contents()
             .filter(function() {
                 // #text nodes
                 return this.nodeType === 3;
             }).map(function() {
                 // get the value and trim it (also removes &nbsp)
                 return $(this).text().trim();
             }).filter(function() {
                 // remove blanks
                 return this != "";
             }).toArray();
```

$("#result").text(result.join());

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hLgvdLrw/)